# some complex domains and boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Could any one tell me  the definition of $\mathbb{C}^{\omega}$ boundary, $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ domain, what is pseudo-convex domain, convex domains? along with  this I want to know suppose I solve one open problem in complex analysis, then how and where to submit it by typing in latex?could any one tell me some open problems in complex analysis and some journal name? I am not attached with any institute, after finishing my master degree in mathematics I am taking care of my mother and teaching in a school nearby, I love complex analysis. so I shall be highly grateful if anyone show me the way how step by step I can be a researcher in complex analysis indipendently.For that I also want suggestion which books I should start reading.